# Finding the Most-Popular MediaWiki Extensions

Tags: php, mediawiki-extensions

Please forgive me if this is a novice question - I'm a neophyte when it comes to MediaWiki.

I'm looking for Video extensions to add to a MediaWiki project.  Some are probably popular and some are arcane.  I would like to choose an extension that lots of other Wikis also use.  Examples of video extensions here:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Video_player_extensions

If this were a WordPress project, I would be able to see the popularity of plug-ins here:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/browse/popular/

Is there a way to find the popularity of MediaWiki extensions?  I've found lots "top-ten" lists, but I'd rather just get straight to the number of Wiki installations that use a given extension.

Thanks and regards,
Ray

Edit: On the MediaWiki mailing list, a colleague suggested the WikiApiary.  Perfect!
https://wikiapiary.com/wiki/Extension:Extensions

Answer (score 6):

The extensions and their popularity can be found here:
https://wikiapiary.com/wiki/Extension:Extensions